# how i install the previous version react-native-pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, pdf

i using `react-native-pdf` but in new version it use `react-native-blob-util` and when i install `react-native-blob-util` its crash.

i read from stackoverflow and google, that it's better to downgrade the `react-native-pdf` because, the downgrade version of `react-native-pdf` why don't use `react-native-blob-util`.

now i have `react-native-pdf` version = 6.4.0

now i want to downgrade to `react-native-pdf`
version = 6.2.0

please someone help me, thankyouu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install any npm module by mentioning the version as well. Remove the package from package.json first, then

```
 npm i react-native-pdf@6.2.0
```

I had faced the same issue last week, so I started using `react-native-view-pdf`  package, its similar and not much code change is required, you can try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can just edit your package.json. Just edit your `"react-native-pdf": "6.4.0"` to `"react-native-pdf": "6.2.0"`. And after that run `npm install` or `yarn`